# All combinations of 2 repetitive elements

Tags: python, binary, combinations, python-itertools

I would like to know all combinations of 0 and 1 that I can obtain in a determinated length list and defining the number of 0 elements and 1 elements.

Sample:

```
Length: 4
Number of 0: 2
Number of 1: 2 (this information is length - number of zeroes)
```

I want to obtain following list:

```
combination = [[0,0,1,1], [0,1,0,1], [0,1,1,0], [1,0,1,0], [1,0,0,1], [1,1,0,0]]
```

I have tried with iterations.product, but I can not define the number of 0 and 1.

I did a filter to group all combinations depending on the sum of the list (if sum is 2, I have all the combinations of my sample). However, I need to know all combinations for a length of 106 elements (0s and 1s) and laptop cannot work.

Comment: "laptop cannot work"?

Comment: Assuming you want N digits, and Z of them zeros, you could find all the ways to choose Z elements from [0..N], which will give you the positions of the zeros.

Comment: I think he means crashing when he tries to do this with a length of 106. It's probably because he's running out of memory, since the number of combinations is enormouse.

Comment: What do you propose to *do* with this ridiculously long list of combinations?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your question is: "list all combinations of an equal number
of zeroes and ones for a given number of zeroes".

We use "product" to iterate over all possible sequences of double the length
of the number of zeroes, filtering out all occurrences where zeroes and
ones are not equal (so sum(list) must be equal to number of zeroes).

Print the length of the list.

Repeat to print the actual list.

This will not work well for large number of zeroes.

```
import itertools

num_zeroes = 2
base_tuple = (0, 1) # * num_zeroes
perms = itertools.product(base_tuple, repeat=2 * num_zeroes)
p2 = itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: sum(x) != num_zeroes, perms)
print(len(list(p2)))
# 6
perms = itertools.product(base_tuple, repeat=2 * num_zeroes)
p2 = itertools.filterfalse(lambda x: sum(x) != num_zeroes, perms)
print(list(p2))
# [(0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0),
#  (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a very nice recursive solution to the problem of generating all binary strings of length `n` with exactly `k` bits set. There are of course `n!/(n!k!)` such strings.

Let's assume we have a function `binaryNK(n, k)` which returns the required set. The key observation is that this set can be partitioned into two subsets:

1. those with a leading 1 followed by each member of `binaryNK(n-1, k-1)`
2. those with a leading 0 followed by each member of `binaryNK(n-1, k)`

Of course, 1 is only valid when `k > 0`, and 2 is only valid when `n > k`. The terminating condition is `n == 0`, at which point we have a solution.

Here's some simple code to illustrate:

```
def binaryNK(s, n, k):
  if n == 0: print(s)

  if k > 0: binaryNK(s+"1", n-1, k-1)
  
  if n > k: binaryNK(s+"0", n-1, k)
    
    
binaryNK("", 5, 2)
```

Output:

```
11000
10100
10010
10001
01100
01010
01001
00110
00101
00011
```